# Blue. Orange. Green. Magenta. What does this strange picture represent?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geometry

Is it text? Is it a face? Is it code? What is it?

[image: What am I?]

Comment: I'd say it's an eyestrain.

Comment: Yeah, the coloring is about as subtle as the decor on a Carnival Cruise.

Comment: I see dead pixels!  They don't know they're dead. [where are they?]  They're everywhere

Comment: It looks like a painting by Victor Vasareli.  https://ashadedviewonfashion.com/2019/02/05/vasareli-sharing-forms-february-6-may-6-the-first-major-parisian-exhibition-devoted-to-victor-vasarely-1906-1997/#jp-carousel-253423

Comment: Oooh! Yeah it does :) Especially this one: https://ashadedviewonfashion.com/2019/02/05/vasareli-sharing-forms-february-6-may-6-the-first-major-parisian-exhibition-devoted-to-victor-vasarely-1906-1997/#jp-carousel-253423

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a

> Hilbert curve

And here is why

> If you look carefully you can see that every blue dot is left of a blue square, every orange dot is right of an orange square, magenta dots are above magenta squares and green dots are below green squares.
>  If you connect each blue dot to the matching square right, and similarily each orange dot to the square left, each magenta dot down and each green dot up you can see the familiar Hilbert curve emerge.
>  If you prefer, the grid are instructions on how to draw the Hilbert curve.  The dots give the direction: green=N, blue=E, magenta=S, orange=W.  The square color confirms the move.

And a picture is worth a 1000 words.

> [image]

PS: maybe related but completely irrelevant, it looks like a Vasarely painting.
http://pinkmartini-art.blogspot.com/2009/10/victor-vasarely-1906-1997.html
see the 5th from the top.